# Angular & Firebase.Firestore: private and public collection of users

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm working on a social-media app.


When a user registers with the app, a new 'user' object is created in the 'users' collection in Firestore. (users to be registered in order to be signed in)

```
export interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string | null;
  photoURL: string | null;

  created: firestore.Timestamp | null;
  nickname: string | null;
  gender: Gender | null;
  isRegistered: boolean;

  birthday: firestore.Timestamp | null;
  location: string | null;

  phone: string | null;
  firstName: string | null;
  lastName: string | null;
}
```

Each 'user' object contains all the data about the respective user.


After the registration process the user is redirected to the welcome page, where a table with other registered users is displayed. To achieve this we call usersService.loadUsers({ limit: 25 }).


We obviously don't want to load the 'users' collection, because that would retrieve user objects with **all the users' data**, even the private fields (birthday, phone, firstName, lastName, etc.).


**What would be the best approach to structure the database, If I wanted to retrieve only the public facing data of all other users?**

My thoughts are as follows:

1. create a new collection - e.g. 'publicUsers'
2. when a new user registers, a new 'user' object is created in the 'users' collection
3. the process of registering a new user would trigger a cloud function that would create a copy of the 'user' object in the 'publicUsers' collection - **with private data removed**

Is this viable or are there some better (industry standard) ways of achieving this?

Comment: There is no real "industry standard" for nosql data modeling.  Choose whatever meets the requirements of your app.  Every app is different.  Separating public and private data is common in order to meet requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My thoughts are as follows:
>
> - create a new collection - e.g. 'publicUsers'
> - when a new user registers, a new 'user' object is created in the 'users' collection
> - the process of registering a new user would trigger a cloud function that would create a copy of the 'user' object in the
>     'publicUsers' collection - with private data removed
>
> Is this viable or are there some better (industry standard) ways of
>   achieving this?

This is indeed a totally viable approach and probably the best, with regards to your requirements.

It is totally classical, in the NoSQL world, to duplicate data in order to fulfill your needs in terms of querying: in your case a "query mode" with all data and another "query mode" with public data only.